# What is the proper way to wire up event notifications for IPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, inotifypropertychanged

Which of these two is the proper way to wire up change-notification for the IPropertyChangedNotification interface?

```
someObj.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SomeObjPropChanged);
someObj.PropertyChanged += SomeObjPropChanged;
```

Both of these seem to work, but I'm not really clear on the difference.  Is one just a shortcut for the other, or can it by any chance have to do with memory management and unintentionally keeping things around? (I've read that there are issues with wiring up change notifications and event handlers causing potential memory leaks thanks to objects unintentionally becoming rooted.)

So any takers?

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find they result in the same IL.

Update:

```
PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SomeEventHandler);
PropertyChanged += SomeEventHandler;
```

Results in IL using ildasm:

```
    IL_0006:  l4zyOP
    IL_0007:  nop
//000011:           PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SomeEventHandler);
    IL_0008:  ldarg.0
    IL_0009:  ldarg.0
    IL_000a:  ldftn      instance void StackOverflow_5535253.SomeClass::SomeEventHandler(object, class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    IL_0010:  newobj     instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0015:  call       instance void StackOverflow_5535253.SomeClass::add_PropertyChanged(class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler)
    IL_001a:  nop
//000012:           PropertyChanged += SomeEventHandler;
    IL_001b:  ldarg.0
    IL_001c:  ldarg.0
    IL_001d:  ldftn      instance void StackOverflow_5535253.SomeClass::SomeEventHandler(object, class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    IL_0023:  newobj     instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0028:  call       instance void StackOverflow_5535253.SomeClass::add_PropertyChanged(class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler)
    IL_002d:  nop
```

Comment: Have you verified that yourself?  If so, I'd love to see an example.  If you post one and that's what it shows, you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## There is absolutely no difference.

Comment: That's a mighty big font there! :)

Comment: Been there! :) I'll pose the same thing to you as the others... do you have any reference to this fact, or can you provide some sample IL that shows this? (I've never personally played with IL so I wouldn't know how to check myself.)

Comment: @MarquelV, Download LINQPad.  It shows you the IL generated from C# statement/program/expression

Comment: Gave you a +1 for the LINQpad reference.  Still trying to get it to work mind you, but hey... if I can, you'll also get the answer. (Plus, technically you did answer first.)

Answer (score 0):

`someObj.PropertyChanged += SomeObjPropChanged` is just a shortcut which is expanded to `someObj.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(SomeObjPropChanged)` by the C# compiler. I prefer the first way, because it looks clearer to me.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm looking for something difinitive... documentation or IL for instance.